# Mysql Views with Index

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have an indexed view in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244226/is-it-possible-to-have-an-indexed-view-in-mysql)

Possible duplicate:
[Is it possible to have an indexed view in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244226/is-it-possible-to-have-an-indexed-view-in-mysql)

---

Is it possible to create Index for Mysql Views Like Tables?

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244226/is-it-possible-to-have-an-indexed-view-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nope](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-restrictions.html)