# MySQL: Materialized Views?

Tags: mysql, database, materialized-views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have an indexed view in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244226/is-it-possible-to-have-an-indexed-view-in-mysql)

Does MySQL support Materialized Views (for crazy fast SELECT performance)?

If so, how do I create one?

Comment: http://www.materialized.info/ you can use trigger to implements

Answer (score 0):

http://flexviews.sourceforge.net/index.html

As close as I can find.