# SQL comparing to the rightmost characters of a column in a very large table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Using MySQL with a very large table (millions of entries), I need to find a row according to the 6 rightmost letters in one of its (indexed) fields.

I've tried using: `SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE field LIKE '%abcdef'`

and `SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE RIGHT(field,6) = 'abcdef'`

Both queries take about 8.5 seconds to complete.
For comparison, should I use the = operator with the whole of the field, it'll take 0.15 seconds.

The only idea I have in mind right now is to create an additional indexed column in the table containing the 6 rightmost letters of the field, and use the = operator against it.

Any more elegant suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The only idea I have in mind right now is to create an additional indexed column in the table containing the 6 rightmost letters of the field, and use the = operator against it.

This is exactly the way to do it in MySQL.

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't yet support [indexes on expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-expressional.html) or [indexed views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921.aspx), so you have to do it the way you suggested.

**Related**

- [Is it possible to have an indexed view in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244226/is-it-possible-to-have-an-indexed-view-in-mysql)
- [MySQL Bugs: #4490 - Functional indexes](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4990)

Comment: A bit of a disappointment, I must say, but if that's the best way, so be it.